# DELL PowerEdge R710 RAM upgrade

Tags: memory, dell-poweredge

I have the following configuration:

36GB MEMORY FOR 2CPU

- 6X4GB on bank #1 (A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3)
- 6X2GB  on bank#2 (A4, A5, A6, B4, B5, B6)

[Visualization of DIMM slots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnR9L.png)

I have another 6x16GB memories that I want to add.

Would it better to put the 16 GB memories in the place of 2 GB memories or to add them in the bank #3?

According to the [manual](http://www.dell.com/downloads/emea/products/pedge/en/installing_upgrading_ddr3_memory_11g.pdf) using all three banks will make memories run at 800 MHz.

Also which memory mode would be bettrer, ECC or Optimized?

> Advanced ECC Mode This mode uses two MCHs and “ties” them together to
>   emulate a 128-bit data bus DIMM. This is primarily used to achieve a
>   Single Device Data Correction (SDDC) for DIMMs based on x8 DRAM
>   technology. SDDC is supported with x4 based DIMMs in every memory
>   mode. One MCH is completely un-utilized, and any memory installed in
>   this channel will generate a warning message during POST.
>
> Memory Optimized Mode In this mode, the MCHs run independently of each
>   other; for example, one can be idle, one can be performing a write
>   operation, and the other can be preparing for a read operation. Memory
>   may be installed in one, two, or three channels. To fully realize the
>   performance benefit of the memory optimized mode, all three channels
>   per CPU should be populated. This implies that some ‘atypical’ memory
>   configurations, such as 3GB, 6GB, or 12GB, will yield the best
>   performance. This is the recommended mode unless specific RAS features
>   are needed.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several guidelines that you need to adhere specifically for your server.

The population method is based on Ranks, assuming you have single and dual ranked modules, and 16 GB Quad Ranks, the following will apply

You must install the 16 GB modules in the white levered slots:

1) 16 GB's Bank #1 (A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3)

2) 4 GB's Bank#2 (A4, A5, A6, B4, B5, B6)

3) 2 GB's Bank#3 (A4, A5, A6, B4, B5, B6)

But of course, I am sure of the first bank. The rest is my assumption from the manual. Please refer the manual, Page 129

For the complete manual Click [here](http://downloads.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_ser_stor_net/esuprt_poweredge/poweredge-r710_Owner%27s%20Manual_en-us.pdf)

Good luck.